# permission denied when using service account with Google scp command

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to use CircleCI to deploy my code to Compute Engine instance. I have created a Service Account user and use gcloud scp command below:

`gcloud --quiet compute scp --recurse dev/test/ [DEST_INSTANCE]:/var/www/dev/dev/test --zone=northamerica-northeast1-a --project [PROJECT_NAME]`

to upload files to var subfolder and the deployment fails with the error below:

```
scp: /var/www/dev/dev/test: Permission denied
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
Exited with code 1
```

Now, I want to grant access to the service account but I don't see it in the list of users to grant access to when I use `cat /etc/passwd`. How can I grant permission to a service account? The roles I have assigned to this account is:
[image]

Comment: Please use the following commands to make sure you are using the correct service account or username:
$ gcloud auth list
$ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`

Comment: can you also run the gcloud scp command using verbose output (--verbosity debug)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your username does not have permissions on the GCE VM to write to `/var/www/dev/dev/test`.

**To solve your issue** you can choose one of two workarounds:

1. Change permissions:

   - give your username write access to `/var/www/dev/dev/test` directly, for example:

     `sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/dev/dev/test`
   - copy files with [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) directly to `/var/www/dev/dev/test`.
2. Copy files in two steps:

   - use [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) to transfer files/directories where your user can write to, e.g., `/tmp` or `/home/$USER`;
   - SSH into the VM instance via [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) or via Console and copy files from temporary location using `sudo` to get proper permissions.

**Note** that since this question is about GCE VMs, you cannot SSH directly to a VM instance as `root`, nor can you copy files directly as `root`, for the same reason: `gcloud compute scp` uses `scp` which relies on `ssh` for authentication.

In addition, please have a look at the documentation [Transferring files to instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) section [Transferring files using the gcloud command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#transfergcloud).

Answer (score 1):

Please check the service account in use. There's one service account that's default for GCE and created by GCP. The other one is the one you created.

If you're using the one you created, have you authorized login for the service account using the JSON key file?

Answer (score 0):

Activate the correct service account for which you have granted the roles in your screenshot by using the command:

gcloud auth activate-service-account $account --key-file=the_key_file.json